# Increase Garbage Collector usage without memory leak

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

So i have a Node application which slow down every minute.

I used some profilers (`nodetime`, `StrongLoop`, `memwatch`) to find where this degraded performance come from : garbage collection operations takes longer after each request.

According to `StrongLoop`, my heap size and memory post V8 full GC are almost constant, heap instance count and heap memory usage do not grow.
However, the RSS (Resident Set Size) never stop growing. I believe this is the trigger for the nearly 120 cycles of GC / HTTP request, consuming nearly all CPU.

Any idea where this RSS can come from, and if this has anything to do with increased GC cycles?

[graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuqqT.jpg)

Comment: what node version you were using? cluster ? have you tried jxcore ? how many keys stored in the dictionaries ? circular references ?

Comment: node v0.10.26 (same with lastest 0.11), no cluster but a few domains (restify routes). Using pm2 for load balancing (same problem with only one node instance). No keys stored in dictionaries (no state between requests), no known circular references.